# Calculating integral $ \int_L A \cdot dr$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve an integral $ \int_L A  \cdot dr$, where $ L$ is $ r=1+t,\theta = \frac \pi 4, \phi = \pi t , t: 0 \to 2$ . Note that $r, \theta, \phi$ are spherical coordinates.

I have $$dr = h_r e_r dr + h_\theta e_\theta d\theta + h_\phi e_\phi d\phi$$
$$ dr = 1 \cdot e_r dr + r \cdot e_\theta d\theta + r \sin\theta \cdot e_\phi d\phi$$
$$ dr =  (e_r + (1+t)e_\theta + (1+t)\sin\frac \pi 4 e_\phi )dt$$

And here it is where I have a different answer than what was given by my solution sheet, which is $ dr = (e_r + \pi r \sin\theta e_\phi) dt $, which I do not understand where the $\pi$ came from, and also where the $e_\theta$ term went?

Comment: You should mark the vector $dr$ differently than the scalar $dr$, for example in bold style.

Comment: @md2perpe How do you get the π, and where did the eθ term went?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$d\vec r = h_r \, e_r \, dr + h_\theta \, e_\theta \, d\theta + h_\phi \, e_\phi \, d\phi.$ Here we have $h_r = 1, \ h_\theta = r, \ h_\phi = r \sin\theta,$ and since $r=1+t, \ \theta = \frac \pi 4, \ \phi = \pi t$ we have $dr = dt, \ d\theta = 0 \, dt, \ d\phi = \pi \, dt.$ Summing up, we thus get
$$d\vec r = 1 \, e_r \, dt + r \, e_\theta \, 0 \, dt + r \sin\theta \, e_\phi \, \pi \, dt = (e_r + \pi \, r \sin\frac \pi 4 \, e_\phi) \, dt.$$

Thus, to answer your two questions, $\pi$ comes from the derivative of $\phi = \pi t$ and $e_\theta$ went away since $\theta$ is constant so $d\theta = 0.$